# How to rebind event handler after .off() and upon animation completion using CSS selectors and jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate, mouseevent, mouseenter

I am new to JavaScript and attempting to create animated buttons with a mask that changes opacity, revealing what is behind the mask. I am using .mouseenter() and .mouseleave() as my event handlers/listeners.  I would like to wait for the animation to complete before the animation can be called again.  I am trying to use multiple buttons and pass the selector parameter to change the mask selection.  I am turning .off() the event handler for the length of the animation then attempting to turn it back on/re-bind it.

My questions are:

How do I make sure the selector is working properly (if I hover over the second button it triggers animation in the first)?

How do I rebind the event handler to the .button element after unbinding it with .off();?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I am trying to learn how to make my code more modular.  Any suggestions/tips are definitely welcomed!

CODEPEN: http://codepen.io/dclappert/full/eDJkp

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var maskOne = 1;
   var maskTwo = 2;

   setEvent(maskOne, maskTwo);

   function setEvent(maskOne, maskTwo){

       $('#navCon div:nth-child(1)').on().mouseenter(function(){fadeOutMask(maskOne);}).on().mouseleave(function(){fadeInMask(maskOne);});

       $('#navCon div:nth-child(2)').on().mouseenter(function(){fadeOutMask(maskTwo);}).on().mouseleave(function(){fadeInMask(maskTwo);});  

   };

   function fadeOutMask(selector){
       $('#navCon div:nth-child('+selector+') div:nth-child('+selector+')')
       .css({opacity: 0.75}).delay(500).animate({opacity: 0}, 2000);

       turnOffEventHandler(selector);

       setTimeout(function(){turnOnEventHandler();},2000);

   };

   function fadeInMask(selector){

      $('#navCon div:nth-child('+selector+') div:nth-child('+selector+')')
      .css({opacity: 0.0}).delay(500).animate({opacity: 0.75}, 2000);    

   };

   function turnOffEventHandler(selector){

      $('#navCon div:nth-child('+selector+')').off();

   };

   function turnOnEventHandler(){

      setEvent();

   };

});
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "navCon">
    <div class = "button">
        <div class = "mask"></div>
        <text>mouseover</text>
    </div>
    <div class = "button">
        <div class = "mask"></div>
        <text>mouseover</text>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
text{font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; font-size: 20px;color: #f1f1f1;}

.button{osition: relative; display:table; background:#2d2d2d; height:100px; width:300px;margin-top:10px;}

.mask{position:absolute; height:100px; width:300px; background: #d4d4d4; z-index: 1; opacity:0.75;}
```

Comment: You are simply calling `turnOnEventHandler()` ... turn of whose handler..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the button below to run the code.  See comments in my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // pass a jquery object to setevent, in this case an array of elements with the class .mask
  setEvent($('.mask'));

  function setEvent($masks) {
    // by convention $ in front of the variable name means the variable contains a jQuery object.

    $masks.each(function() {
      $(this).on().mouseenter(function() {
        fadeOutMask($(this));
      });

      // the following is unnecessary since you'll never trigger the fadeInMask with a mouseleave, only with turnOnEventHandler below

      /* .on().mouseleave(function() {
        fadeInMask($(this));
      });  */
    });



  };

  function fadeOutMask($mask) {
    $mask
      .css({
        opacity: 0.75
      }).delay(500).animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, 2000);

    turnOffEventHandler($mask);

    setTimeout(function() {
      turnOnEventHandler($mask);
    }, 2000);

  };

  function fadeInMask($mask) {
    $mask
      .css({
        opacity: 0.0
      }).delay(500).animate({
        opacity: 0.75
      }, 2000);

  };

  function turnOffEventHandler($mask) {

    $mask.off();

  };

  function turnOnEventHandler($mask) {
    // when you call setEvent this time, you're passing the $mask object which points only to the one that was moused-over.
    setEvent($mask);
    // manually call in the fadeIn
    fadeInMask($mask);

  };

});
```

```css
text {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.button {
  osition: relative;
  display: table;
  background: #2d2d2d;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #d4d4d4;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navCon">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="mask"></div>
      <text>mouseover</text>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <div class="mask"></div>
      <text>mouseover</text>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```